# Twilio Programmable chat - Error 0:3 Request to EMS service has failed, unable to set FPA token

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I am using twilio programmable chat for website and mobile apps (andriod and ios). We are generating a token from sever (PHP) and it seems be working fine on web. But on mobile Apps it return below Errors:

**Andriod**: Error 0:3 Request to EMS service has failed, unable to set FPA token.

**iOS**: <<<>>> Chat-iOS[0]:        0x16d503000 | 08/24/22:29:55.726 | FATAL    | Chat-iOS | Error validating token: 3

I have removed the endpoint from token as mentioned in other thread but no luck after that as well. Please assist to fix this error on mobile Apps.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Update your sdk version to **3.1.0**

```
implementation 'com.twilio:chat-android:3.1.0'
```